# Opening StoryBoard in XCode automatically adds ~100 auto layout warnings when I open a project and they won't go away when I click "Update Frames"

Tags: xcode, autolayout, storyboard, warnings

This might be hard to diagnose without seeing the project, but Xcode keeps adding tons of warnings to my storyboard. It is a source controlled project, and if a team member cleans up all the warnings, pushes, and I pull, the warnings go away but as soon as I open storyboard, they reappear and they do not go away when I do the standard Update Frames option.

A lot of them seem to have to do with Stackviews, but I'm just confused why my coworkers can get the warnings to disappear and I cannot.

Has anyone experienced anything like this, or have any tips on how to approach solving this?

I was using Xcode 7.3 but after updating to 7.3.1 the problem still persists. Running OS X 10.11.6

Edit: Just to add some specifics, when I look at the source code versus my local code, it basically adds a ton of "Misplaced" tags, and a lot of values are changed by 0.5 or 1 pixel.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the exact same issue when working with others on the same storyboard. It will happen every time you open (or another colleague) the storyboard. Here are some advises to avoid this :

- When I open the storyboard, I know it will provoke this warnings. So if I don't add anything, before pushing a new commit, I reset any changes on the storyboard
- I've come up with another good solution : using storyboard references as much as I can. So what I do is basically creating a storyboard for every flows (sometimes you can even have one storyboard for one controller). That way, when I work on a part of a project, it won't generate warnings on the totality of the storyboard. It avoids epic merge with many conflicts, it is easier to maintain, and it's faster to work on a small storyboard than on a huge one (Xcode is powerful, but when you have big storyboard, at a certain point it will lag).

But to answer to your question, I think everyone have that same issue when working on big projects, hopefuly apple will solve that one day, but for the moment you have to set good practices with your team. This is the only way to avoid wasting time at every pull ;) (at least for me, maybe someone has a better solution).